# How can I make a destroyer that destroys all the overtaken platforms in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a unity project for an exam I'm attending, so I'm not really good at unity, hope you can help.
I'm doing this 2d endless runner game and I created an empty object to set inactive all the platforms that the player has overtaken. The object moves forward and when its position is > than the platform position, it sets it inactive (since destroying them also removes them from the list so it wouldnt work for others platforms of the same kind). My problem is that I've created a list in which I put all the types of my prefabs but the way I did it, it only sets inactive the first prefab of a kind and then stops working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DistruttoreLivelli : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public List<GameObject> objs;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (objs[i].transform.position.x < transform.position.x)
            {
                objs[i].SetActive(false);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

How can I manage to make it go forever? I tried to use a while but it makes unity crash. :/
Ty for the help!

Comment: I assume you're getting an out of range exception. Try `i < objs.Count` instead.

Comment: @RetiredNinja doesnt work, the problem is that it will set inactive only the first kind of the prefab, if i use the same prefab 3 times, it will work just once. I think i need a method to restart the loop as soon as it ends

Comment: It already runs once a frame. It sounds like you have a different problem than you think, but the `<=` is a definite bug.

Comment: You dont show enough code.  As you dont show how you are adding to the list

Comment: i just drag the prefabs into the script in the inspector, tell me what you need to see

Comment: @RetiredNinja and what could it be?

Comment: maybe its just some unity setting?

Comment: @BugFinder i'll try with an example, if i have  3 types of prefabs, platform 1, platform 2 and platform 3, i put them manually in the script in the inspector. what i want the script to do is, when a platform 1,2 or 3 has spawned, the empty gameobject that moves endlessly forward (that has the script) detects when it went past the platform and set it inactive. then if another platform 1,2 or 3 spawn it does the same thing over and over. where is my code wrong? :/

Comment: As before. You need to show minimum viable code as you dont show how you add to the list we can’t really tell you whats wrong.

Comment: how can i show you the code to add to the list if there is no code...i just drag the prefabs and put them in the script

Comment: When you spawn the instances do you add them to a list that you can iterate through and disable? It sounds like you're trying to disable the prefabs and not the actual spawned objects.

Comment: you are right. I created a method that returns the whole list of the objects that are spawning ( called getPooled()) and, setting objs=pooled.getPooled(), i changed the script in this way:   void Update()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < objs.Count; i++)
        {
            if (objs[i].GetChild(1).position.x < transform.position.x)
            {
                Destroy(objs[i]);
            }

        }
    }       now i can see objs filling with the platforms spawning but the script still wont destroy the platforms

Comment: the problem might be that im using Transforms, i tried to Destroy(objs[i].gameObject) but didnt change

Comment: i deleted getchild sice it didnt make any sense

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to make it endless is to move the objects to the furthest position instead of deactivating them. Instead of `objs[i].SetActive(false);` it should be something like:

```
    Vector3 endOfTheLinePos = objs[i].transform.position;
    endOfTheLinePos .x = maxX;
    objs[i].transform.position = endOfTheLinePos;
```

With `maxX` being a float parameter of the highest value of x that you are using on the objects.

Also, as already pointed out, on the for you should use `i < objs.Count` instead.

Comment: doesnt this way continues to build up resources over time that would eventually lead to memory errors? also i need to make the script works on ALL the platforms, i dont think the problem is what i do with the prefabs themselves, since the script only works for the first prefab of that kind

Comment: i still tried it and it still works on the first one of each kind

Comment: This way doesn't instantiate anything new, you would be looping the object positions instead of disabling them. It is not the best way to implement since you would have all objects active even when not in the camera (lets say you have 100 platforms moving while only 5 are shown for example).

Is it possible to provide more info? Maybe a print of the scene showing the inspector on the script you mentioned.

Comment: @leonardomoreo I think I got what is wrong, from your other comment. I think you are testing the position of the prefabs instead of the instances. The way I imagined, was that you had all the instances placed on the scene from the editor and they were the ones on the `objs[]`.

Comment: and how do i change that?

Comment: One way would be to add a Script into the objects that tests its own position and once it reaches the x from the player (which I imagine is a constant value), the object destroys itself. Something like: ` if (transform.position.x < playerX) { Destroy(gameObject); }` inside the Update. Probably could add that to the script you use to move the objects too.

Comment: sadly its the player that moves, not the platform, and i cant make it the other way since i cant attach the player to a prefab, but this method made me think of using OnTriggerEnter2D, but it still doesnt work... here is the code:                                                                                  public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            Destroy(obj);
        }
    } where obj is the platform itself

Comment: That is a valid way of doing it. You would need a second collider behind the player to catch the objects that he doesn't collide with. Also the player and that object would need a rigidbody2D or a CharacterController (not sure if this one has a 2D version) for this collision to be detected

Comment: for some reasons it doesnt work

Comment: it might be cause ive been looking at my code for straight 3 hours, so... i attach the script to the platform, attach the platform to the script and put a collider and a rigid body to both the player and the platform and should be it?

Comment: I made a project here to test some things. The player and the 'end of the line' objects need a 2D Collider, a rigidbody2D (that cant be static) and you need to set their tags. While the prefab need just a collider with IsTrigger enabled. The trigger will run on the prefab's instance that you created.



You could put a `Debug.Log(collision.tag, collision.gameObject);` before the if inside the OnTriggerEnter2D to ensure if the event is maybe triggering but you had the wrong tag selected


Also I am not sure what is the 'obj' you are destroying, shouldn't it be 'gameObject' instead?

Comment: i forgot to enable isTrigger, now it destroys them, but how can i make the player collides with the platform when isTrigger is enabled?

Comment: ive changed OnTriggerEnter2D to OnCollisionEnter2D and now it all works perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: also ive used "obj" because the prefab is made up of multiple platforms, so i attach the script to the last platform, and put "obj" as the whole prefab to destroy all of it

Comment: Happy it worked in the end!